# Why is the $0$th percentile of the standard normal distribution $-\infty$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Why is the $0$th percentile of the standard normal distribution $-\infty$?

I can't explain the cause except saying there is no area under the curve. So it goes beyond the bell-shaped curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken calculus? It is because
$$\lim_{t, x \to -\infty}\int\limits_{t}^{x}f(s)\text{ d}s = 0$$
where $f$ is the equation of the graph of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Why upper limit and lower limit both are $-\infty$?

Comment: oh, if both the upper and lower limit is $-\infty$ or same value, then the integral is $0$.